# window destruction error in Tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, window, exit

I'm trying to create a Hangman game GUI using Tkinter. I have fully working code apart from several things. I want to create a loop that would restart the game by button press or quit the game by pressing "no".

I also want for these buttons to appear in new window and close the window before.

I've removed not needed parts of the code so you would only see main problem area and main idea. To make it work you just need to type in "b" and then "o":

```
from Tkinter import *
item = "BOO"
oldString = "-" * (len(item))
blank = "-" * (len(item))
guesses = 10

def start():
    winMain.destroy()
    mainMenu()


def theWinner():
    def end():
        root.destroy()

    def replay():
        root.destroy()
        mainMenu()

    root = Tk()
    root.title("HANGMAN GAME DEMO")
    answer = Entry(root)
    answer.insert(END, "You Won!!! Play again?")
    answer.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    yesB=Button(root, text = "Yes", command = replay)
    yesB.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    noB = Button(root, text = "Quit", command = end)
    noB.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    root.mainloop()


def mainMenu():
    def gameOn():
        global guesses
        global oldString
        newString = ""
        i = 0
        x = len(item)
        hanged = ""
        readString = answerIn.get().upper()
        winner = 1
        if readString not in item:
            guesses -= 1
        elif readString in item:
            while x > 0:
                if item[i] != readString:
                    newString = newString + oldString[i]
                elif item[i] == readString:
                    newString = newString + readString
                i +=1   
                x -=1

            oldString = newString
            out.config(state=NORMAL)
            out.delete(0,END)
            out.insert(0,oldString);
            out.config(state=DISABLED)
            answerIn.delete(0,END)
            if oldString == item:
                win.destroy()
                theWinner()


        newString = ""
        i=0
        x=len(item)

        answerIn.delete(0,END)

    win = Tk()
    win.geometry ("665x480")
    win.title("HANGMAN GAME DEMO")
    win.configure(background='LightBlue2')

   #Display of the word user is trying to guess
    guessWord = Entry(win, disabledbackground = "mint cream", disabledforeground = "black", font="helvetica 11 bold", width = 12, border = 2)
    guessWord.grid(row=1, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 6, sticky = W)
    guessWord.insert(END, "The word is: ")
    guessWord.config(state = DISABLED)
    #guessWord = Label(win, bg = "mint cream", font="helvetica 10 ", text = "The word you have to guess is: ")
    guessWord.grid(row=1, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 9, sticky = W)
    out = Entry(win, border = 2,  font="helvetica 15 bold", width = 12, disabledforeground = "black", disabledbackground = "gold")
    out.insert(0,blank);
    out.config(state=DISABLED)
    out.grid(row=1, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 200, sticky = W)


    #Type in Window
    answer = Entry(win, disabledbackground = "mint cream", disabledforeground = "black", font="helvetica 10", width = 21, border = 2)
    answer.grid(row=2, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 8, sticky = W)
    answer.insert(END,"Please type in the letter: ")
    answer.config(state=DISABLED)
    answerIn = Entry(win,width = 3, border = 2)
    answerIn.focus_set()
    answerIn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 200, sticky = W)

    b = Button(win, text = "Enter",command = gameOn, bg = "chartreuse2", font="helvetica 10 bold",)
    b.grid(row=2, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 200)


    win.mainloop()

winMain = Tk()
winMain.title("HANGMAN GAME DEMO")
imageLabel = Label(winMain, text = "HELLO!")
imageLabel.pack()
winMain.after(1000, start)
winMain.mainloop()
```

If I press "no", I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Python27/8.py", line 69, in gameOn
    answerIn.delete(0,END)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2509, in delete
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'delete', first, last)
TclError: invalid command name ".94412392"
```

If I press "yes", it does not seem to restart the game from the start. It only lets me enter one character before bringing Win window again.

Where am I going wrong and is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: The error when you quit is fine, it will happen when you destroy.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because after destroying the window you want to delete the content in the `entry widget`. See this part

```
def mainMenu():
    .......
    .......
    ......
    if oldString == item:
           win.destroy()
           theWinner()


   # newString = ""
   # i=0
   # x=len(item)

 #   answerIn.delete(0,END)
```

You can see i commented that part you don't need it after closing the window when you do that the error wont pop up again.With regards to the game not starting it thing you should create another function with the same command for for it because

```
def replay():
    root.destroy()
    mainMenu()
```

it isn't working when you call it.I will also suggest you use `Toplevel` window rather than calling `Tk` and `mainloop` more than one.

check this link out `[Toplevel documentation][1]` .It hard for everyone to debug your code because you are creating several function under another function separate them.

Comment: I did have all my functions separately but then it would not recognize the commands. When I try to root.destroy() without the function inside the function, it keeps claiming that this variable does not exist.

Comment: use it as global variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `oldString` when you end a game:

Replace

```
if oldString == item:
    win.destroy()
    theWinner()
```

With

```
if oldString == item:
    win.destroy()
    oldString='---'
    theWinner()
```

And it should work (I have tested).

Answer (score -1):

Without trying to solve your issue on your codebase I do recommend to switch the code to be class based, that way you are more in control and can easier keep references which are needed to make some of this gui-stuff work as expected. A bonus will be that you can ditch the `globals` you have as well.

There is an excellent py2 [tkinter doc](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf) from where this minimal example is copied just to give an idea of the class based style of coding for gui's, which generally is the prefered way of doing it. You seem to be on py2, however if you're on py3 the docs works as well, you just have to keep track of the minor differences in the imports.

```
import Tkinter as tk
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()

app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```